# if statement function for 1 value but for more than 1 validation

Tags: if-statement, tableau-api

i have some problem when i created a calculated field in tableau.

lets say i have this "City" variable with these kind of data:
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8

i want to make validate this number into if 1-4 become Region A, 5-8 become Region B and 1-8 is National.

this is my calculated filed code

```
if [City]=1 or [City]=2 or [City]=3 or [City]=4 THEN "Region A"
elseif [City]=5 or [City]=6 or [City]=7 or [City]=8 THEN "Region B"
elseif [City]=1 or [City]=2 or [City]=3 or [City]=4 or [City]=5 or [City]=6 or 
[City]=7 or [City]=8 THEN "National"
END
```

but after i created this calculated field, only "Region A" and "Region B" and "Null" showed. My thought is maybe that code is overlapping on Region with National (or is not?).

How can i solve this? and where this null come from when my data only have the range from 1-8?

Thank you

edited :

Hi all, just want to confirm that the way i wanted it to look like is with 1 calculated field, when I clicked "Region A" it will show combination of city 1-4, when I clicked "Region B" it will show combination of city 5-6, and when i clicked "National" it will show combination of city 1-8.

Comment: You IF statement will never be National because it will be TRUE for values 1-8 to either Region A or Region B. I'm confused as to your desired result. It appears that all Cities are captured as National. So how will this be used as the end result?

Comment: hi @Bernardo end result should be when i clicked on Region A it will show city from 1-4, when i clicked on Region B it will show city from 5-8 and when i clicked on National it will show city from 1-8 and i should be on 1 calculated field.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: After the clarification in the comments, what you need is a parameter. Create one that can take the values "Region A", "Region B" and "National". 
Then create a calculated field with (I didn't use all city values to make it more readable):

```
CASE [parameter]:
WHEN "Region A" THEN IF [city] = 1 or [city] = 2 THEN [value] END
WHEN "Region B" THEN IF [city] = 3 or [city] = 4 THEN [value] END
WHEN "National" THEN [value] END
END
```

With the parameter you can now choose the grouping. For [value] you will need to insert the column you want to display (ie. Sales). If [city] has a value that is according to your criteria, it will populate the new calculated field with the value, if it is not, it will be empty, and if it is "National" then it will always use the value you defined.

Old Answer:

It sounds like you want to create a hierarchical structure to display your data on city, region and country level. 
If that is the case you have a few options:

1. **You have actual city names instead of 1, 2, 3** in your city column: Tableau will create the hirachy automatically if you define the column as a geographic role.
2. **You have 1,2,3 but only one country**: create one field `Region` with the formula you already have but leave the last ELSEIF out:

   > ```
   > if [City]=1 or [City]=2 or [City]=3 or [City]=4 THEN "Region A"
   > elseif [City]=5 or [City]=6 or [City]=7 or [City]=8 THEN "Region B"
   > end
   > ```

   Then create a second calculated field `Country` and just give it the value `'National'`
   In your dimensions you can now create a hirachy by dragging and dropping th region and city field on top of the country field.
3. **You have 1,2,3 and several countries**: replace the value in the second calculated field with this formula and create the hirachy as in 2.:

   > ```
   > if [City]=1 or [City]=2 or [City]=3 or [City]=4 or [City]=5 or [City]=6 or 
   > [City]=7 or [City]=8 THEN "Country1"
   > elseif [City]=9 or [City]=10 or [City]=11 THEN "Country2"
   > END
   > ```

A few further notes on that:

- You probably want to use a `CASE` instead of that many `IF`, as it is easier to read and better to maintain
- You might want to base it on the regions instead of the cities since you will only need to maintain eg 2 Regions for your original example versus 8 cities.

Comment: hi @Alexander thanks for share. Actually what i wanted is not a hirarchical structure. Your answer probably will come out like National -> Region A or National -> Region B. What i wanted is when i clicked on Region A it will show city from 1-4, when i clicked on Region B it will show city from 5-8 and when i clicked on National it will show city from 1-8, and 3 of these categories should be in 1 calculated field. Any ideas?

Comment: @randy you can do that with a parameter. Will update the answer when I am home

Comment: @RandyAdhitama changed my answer. should work as you described now